# How to save converted js object to JSON file to specified file path using jquery or Php

Tags: php, jquery

```
var jsonsData =JSON.stringify(parsed, null);

        $("<a />", 
             {
                 "download": fileId +".json",
             "href" : "data:json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(jsonsData),
             }).appendTo("body")
              .click(function()
             {
                  $(this).remove()
             })[0].click()
```

This just download the file '.json' and save it to the download folder.I Want json file to be saved in particular folder path by passing variable(**contain name of a file**)from js file to php file.

Comment: This is not possible, you do not have control over the client side behavior. That is for _very_ good reasons: security.

Comment: You can't do that. It would be a huge security issue if you could.

Comment: You can serve up JSON as a downloadable file, but the client decides where to save said file. You can't force somebody to download it in a specific location. If that were possible, we'd all be using machines riddled with malware

Comment: The only option is to ask the user to save the file to a particular folder.

Comment: can I save the Json file to specified file path folder using jquery or php after stringify the object

Comment: @RobsonJohny Did you really read all the comments and then add you last comment again asking same question that in all of the comments they said **No you can't**?